# Flask Route Prefix for User Group

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application with multiple user roles. All roles need to access an "index" page but the page will be different for each role. To accomplish this, I think the best solution is to add a prefix to certain user roles. For example, an admin role would go to http://admin.myapp.com/index and a partner would go to http://partner.myapp.com/ .

I've seen some information on how to add a route prefix to ALL views, but I only want it to be based on the user's role. What's the best way to accomplish this? Can anybody give me a push in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### My suggestion to go is

you don't need to worry about the domain prefix to solve this problem.

Obviously, you will have the `user` model that has `user` related fields.add a `role` as one of the field for the `user model`

#### user model in models.py

```
class User(db.Model):
      ..........
      ..........
      role = db.Column(db.String(50)) #admin, customer, agent etc..
```

#### views.py

```
@app.route('/index' methods=('GET','POST'))
@login_required
def index_view():
   #get the current logged in user object
   user = current_user or g.user #based on your way of implementation
   if user.role == 'admin':
       return render_to_response('admin_index.html',{'data':'This is admin page'})
   elif user.role == 'agent':
       return render_to_response('agent_index.html',{'data':'This is agent page'})
   else:
       return render_to_response('default_index.html',{'data':'This is default page'})
```

Here, you should add the [`login_required`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) decorator which ensures the `user` to be logged in before access this `view method`

#### additional info:

if you want restrict this `view method` to the particular `user roles`, you can write `@roles_required` decorator which take in the input as `allowed_roles` and returns based on it

#### `roles_required` decorator implementation overview

```
def roles_required(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for i in args:
            user = current_user #get user object
            if user.role == i:
                return func()
    return wrapper
```

once you implemented `roles_required`, add it the corresponding `view` method as we added `@login_required` for the `def index_view()`

```
@roles_required('admin','agent')
```